# Use specialized template and name the enum option

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums

I specialize a template by enum

```
template<>
class specialized_class<user_option=CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION>
{

public:

    typedef second_class<user_option> obj_type;
```

Here, to define `second_class`, I need to know, what type user has selected. I need to name the chosen option. However the second line of my code is an illegal syntax. How to do what I need?

Even though

```
    typedef second_class<CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION> obj_type;
```

solves the problem. I prefer to avoid this way, since it is using a magic type, and the code inside the class needs modification for using somewhere else.

Comment: you can specify CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION in your second line since you know that you are specializing for CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION

Comment: Thanks but that would be a magic type. I prefer to avoid that.

Comment: @ar2015 It's not _magic_. It would be magic if it wasn't clear why that is the value that should/must be used but in this case it is the only possible value because it is the template type you have explicitly used to perform the specialization.

Comment: @JamesAdkison, in practice, if i add another enum option, i do not write the class from scratch. I just copy the specialized class of an option and paste it and do a few tweaks. Imagine six month later when I have forgotten most of my code, your suggestion prone the code to have mistake. It is matter of code maintenance. As far as it is possible, I want to avoid that. If C++ in no way supports it, that would be the last option.

Comment: If by "add another option" you mean add a new value to the enumeration, what affect does this have on the specialized class? Do you mean that you also add a new specialization for the new enumeration value?

Comment: @JamesAdkison, yes, new specialized class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to reduce the occurrences of `CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION` in the specialization. Perhaps the following is sufficient.

```
enum Enum
{
    E1,
    E2
};

template<Enum E>
class Foo
{
};

template<Enum E>
class Bar
{
};

template<>
class Foo<E2> // 1 occurrence to change if copy/pasted for a new specialization
{
public:
    static const Enum enum_value = E2; // Last occurrence to change

    typedef Bar<enum_value> obj_type;
};
```

Comment: It seems, there is no other simple way

Comment: @ar2015 I'm not aware of any other way. If you find out otherwise let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell from the brief example, but you can factor generic parts of the specialization into a base class to avoid some repetition of the parameters.

```
template<CHOICE_ENUM option>
struct user_option_base {
    static const CHOICE_ENUM user_option = option;
};

template<>
class specialized_class<CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION>
    : user_option_base<CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION>
{
public:
    typedef second_class<specialized_class::user_option> obj_type;
```

To avoid qualifying `specialized_class::user_option`, you can use `using user_option_base::user_option;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial specialization along with some sfinae, but the solution ends up with a bit of a wtf-factor. [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3228969725559f0a) a demo.

First, change the primary template

```
template<CHOICE_ENUM e, typename Enable = void>
class specialized_class;
```

The default parameter allows you to continue using `specialized_class` the way you were using it before - you can still pretend its a one parameter class template. Now, convert your full specializations into partial specialization + sfinae:

```
template <CHOICE_ENUM user_option>
class specialized_class<user_option,
      std::enable_if_t<user_option == CHOICE_ENUM::CHOSEN_OPTION>>
{
  //stuff
};
```